# R strucchange vs SAS proc autoreg for bai perron

Tags: r, sas, regression, breakpoints

Results from the R strucchange package do not match the results from SAS proc autoreg when I estimate structural breaks using the Bai and Perron (1998, 2003) minimum BIC.  The number of breaks found is not the same at all.  My data has about 20,000 observations so it is hard for me to re-create the problem on here.  But can anyone please explain why there is a difference in the number of breaks found?  Below is an example of the R and SAS code I use to estimate the breaks.

The R code is:

```
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
library(strucchange)

data.bp <- breakpoints(formula, data)
coeftest(data.bp)
coeftest(data.bp, vcov = NeweyWest)
```

The SAS code is:

```
proc autoreg data=data;
model formula / BP=(EPS=0.15, PRINTEST=BIC);
```

Comment: As @DanielWisehart said: Please provide a data set that reproduces the problem and is as small and simple as possible. The corresponding output from SAS and R would also help (e.g., I have no access to the SAS procedure). Finally note that the computation may be numerically challenging (see e.g. http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jae.856).

Comment: May I please email the data and output from SAS and R to you Professor Zeileis?

Comment: If you send it to me, I'll surely have a look. But if you put it up on some web page and link it here, others could join the discussion as well.

Comment: Professor Zeileis answered my question via email.  If he would like to post his answer on here I will award him the bounty.

Comment: Well, I didn't fully answer your question. I just speculated about the source of the differences between R and SAS (but I'll try to have a closer look that) and pointed out that there are GARCH effects in your data (volatility clustering, heavy tails). The latter do not explain the differences of R vs. SAS but mean that a different model should be adopted anyways...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to say it but you may have to come up with a simpler example for us to help you debug it.  Maybe the strucchange package is wrong, or maybe it is using different assumptions.  I pulled in the source package from here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/index.html and the source is just over 6,500 lines with a least a third of that being test values.  If you come up with a simple example you can share we can look into it further.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  You also might want to look at the source because, as I said, there are test values built into the package that might give you insight into what is being done differently--or wrong, for your needs.

Comment: For my own sanity check, I created some data with obvious breaks, and the SAS and R output matched exactly.  My guess is the breaks in my actual data are more subtle.  The R script finds more breaks than the SAS script in my actual data.

Comment: Possibly, this is some difference in the way the information criterion is computed. Do the BIC values match?